# Java Interface: If we implement an inbuilt interface in java how are we able to get the results of methods from those interface?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, abstract-methods

I would like to know how does an interface methods which are abstract methods (for versions less than java 8) can return a result when the interface is implemented?

For example:

If a class, or one of its superclasses, implements the Cloneable interface, you can use the clone() method to create a copy from an existing object. To create a clone, you write:

aCloneableObject.clone();

In the above example how is the clone() method able to return anything if the method only had its signature present in the cloneable interface?

Example 2:

```
public class C implements Cloneable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        C c = new C();
        c.clone();
    }

}
```

In the above example why is Cloneable interface not throwing any compile time error even if it's methods are not being overridden?

Comment: If you implement an interface, you have to override (implement) all methods from the interface, unless your class is abstract.

Comment: Because you, err, implemented it?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Part of the method signature in the interface is its return type.

Comment: I would like to know why i got downvoted for this question? This is a very important question and u need to understand inheritance to freakin answer it

Answer (score 0):

Because that clone method should be declared in a class which implements the interface. You can't declare an interface object, you'll always declare an object which belongs to a class that implements the interface.

Wrong

```
Interface myOBject = new Interface()
```

Right

```
Interface myOBject = new ClassThatImplementsTheInterface()
```

ClassThatImplementsTheInterface is a class that implements the interface and implements all of its methods.

Comment: Hi @ShahidSarwar , Every class in java has Object as a superclass. So your class C is also descendant from Object.

Object has a clone(), so if you're not overriding it, it will the take the method from the superclass (Object) by default

Comment: thank you.. I read the documentation and this is exactly what it said! thanks man